# unable to append to the data frame

Tags: r

Here is my code to pull xml files, parse it and then append the parsed xml file to a data frame called new_df. 
I am noticing that new_df is empty. It should not be empty. I cannot figure it out, any ideas is greatly appreciated.

```
library(RODBC)
library(XML)
setInternet2(TRUE)
options(timeout=200)

agentlist<-c(45693,42627,42483,42432,40187)
slotlist<-c(1135863,1145649,1135859,1135844)

for (i in 1:length(agentlist)) {
    for(j in 1:length(slotlist)) {
      if(slotlist[j]==1135863) {
        for (k in 1:8){
              url1<-c("http://api.keynote.com/keynote/api/getgraphdata?api_key=<key>&&slotidlist=")
              url<-paste0(url1, slotlist[j])
             url2<-c("&graphtype=time&timemode=relative&relativehours=432000&timezone=est&bucket=300&averagemethod=GM&transpagelist=")
        url<-paste0(url, url2)
        url<-paste0(url, slotlist[j])
        url<-paste(url, k, sep=':')
        url3<-c("&pagecomponent=u&format=xml&agentlist=")
        url<-paste0(url, url3)
        url<-paste0(url, agentlist[i])
        tryCatch({
            download.file(url, destfile='test1.xml')
            xml_file <- xmlParse("test1.xml")    # Parse the XML
            xml_file <- xmlToList(xml_file)   

            xml_file <- xml_file[names(xml_file) == "measurement"]
            xml_file <- lapply(xml_file, function(x) x[grep("alias|bucket", names(x))])

            xml_file <- lapply(xml_file, function(x) {
            alias <- x$alias
            buckets <- t(sapply(x$bucket_data, unlist))
            cbind("alias" = alias, buckets)
        })

        xml_file <- do.call("rbind", xml_file)

        xml_file <- data.frame(xml_file, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

        x<-xml_file[,c(1,3,7,9)]
        colnames(x)<-c("SITE", "AVAIL_PERCENT", "RESPONSE_TIME", "DATE_TIME")
        x<-x[,c("DATE_TIME", "SITE", "RESPONSE_TIME", "AVAIL_PERCENT")]
                     x$AGENT<-c(agentlist[i])

        temp<-rbind(x, temp)
        },error = function(e) {
        print("unable to download the url")
        })
        }
        new_df<-temp 
                     print(new_df) ###empty data frame




     }else if(slotlist[j]==1145649){
        temp<-data.frame(DATE_TIME=as.POSIXct(character()), SITE=character(), RESPONSE_TIME=as.numeric(character()), AVAIL_PERCENT=as.numeric(character()), AGENT=as.numeric(character()))
        for(l in 1:6) {
            url1<-c("http://api.keynote.com/keynote/api/getgraphdata?api_key=<key>&&slotidlist=")
            url<-paste0(url1, slotlist[j])
            url2<-c("&graphtype=time&timemode=relative&relativehours=432000&timezone=est&bucket=300&averagemethod=GM&transpagelist=")
            url<-paste0(url, url2)
            url<-paste0(url, slotlist[j])
            url<-paste(url, l, sep=':')
            url3<-c("&pagecomponent=u&format=xml&agentlist=")
            url<-paste0(url, url3)
            url<-paste0(url, agentlist[i])
            tryCatch({
                    download.file(url, destfile='test1.xml')

                    xml_file <- xmlParse("test1.xml")    # Parse the XML
                    xml_file <- xmlToList(xml_file)   

                    xml_file <- xml_file[names(xml_file) == "measurement"]
                    xml_file <- lapply(xml_file, function(x) x[grep("alias|bucket", names(x))])

                    xml_file <- lapply(xml_file, function(x) {
                      alias <- x$alias
                      buckets <- t(sapply(x$bucket_data, unlist))
                      cbind("alias" = alias, buckets)
                    })

                    xml_file <- do.call("rbind", xml_file)

                    xml_file <- data.frame(xml_file, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

                    x<-xml_file[,c(1,3,7,9)]
                    colnames(x)<-c("SITE", "AVAIL_PERCENT", "RESPONSE_TIME", "DATE_TIME")
                    x<-x[,c("DATE_TIME", "SITE", "RESPONSE_TIME", "AVAIL_PERCENT")]

                    #x$Site<-gsub('.*\\-(.*)\\-.*', '\\1', x$Site)

                    #x$DateTime<-gsub("AM", "", x$DateTime)
                    #x$DateTime<-gsub("PM", "", x$DateTime)
                    x$DATE_TIME<-as.POSIXct(x$DATE_TIME, format="%Y-%B-%d %H:%M")
                    #x$Response_Time<-as.numeric(x$Response_Time)
                    #x$Avail_Percent<-as.numeric(x$Avail_Percent)
                    x$AGENT<-c(agentlist[i])
                    temp<-rbind(x, temp)
                },error = function(e) {
                    print("unable to download the url")
            })      
        }
        new_df<-temp
                     print(new_df) ### empty data frame

    }
}
}
```

I amd noticidng that new_df data frame is empty. It should not be empty. Any ideas?

Comment: you could use browser() inside your function, to see where things go wrong.

Comment: @babtieste, I inserted browser() after rbind, I get this error: Called from: doTryCatch(return(expr), name, parentenv, handler)

Comment: I'm not sure if tryCatch and browser() play well together, you may want to work without try() for the debugging phase. Also try trace() if that helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should refactor your code in small functions in order to test them separately and get clearer code. Then you should use an `xxapply` function to avoid the side effects (global varibale interactions) that you get in a `for` loop. For example here is what I would do:

1. function to create url
2. function to parse the url and create the data.frame
3. function that call the 2 previous functions...

To generate the url :

```
create.URL <- function (slot, agent,i) {
  url1 <- c("http://api.keynote.com/keynote/api/getgraphdata?api_key=<key>&&slotidlist=")
  url <- paste0(url1, slot)
  url2 <- c(paste0("&graphtype=time&timemode=relative&relativehours=",
            "432000&timezone=est&bucket=300&averagemethod=GM&transpagelist="))
  url <- paste0(url, url2)
  url <- paste0(url, slot)
  url <- paste(url, i, sep=':')
  url3 <- c("&pagecomponent=u&format=xml&agentlist=")
  url <- paste0(url, url3)
  url <- paste0(url, agent)
  url
}
```

To parse the file :

```
parse.URL <- function(url,agent,coerceDate=FALSE){
  download.file(url, destfile='test1.xml')
  xml_file <- xmlParse("test1.xml")    # Parse the XML
  xml_file <- xmlToList(xml_file)   

  xml_file <- xml_file[names(xml_file) == "measurement"]
  xml_file <- lapply(xml_file, function(x) x[grep("alias|bucket", names(x))])

  xml_file <- lapply(xml_file, function(x) {
    alias <- x$alias
    buckets <- t(sapply(x$bucket_data, unlist))
    cbind("alias" = alias, buckets)
  })

  xml_file <- do.call("rbind", xml_file)

  xml_file <- data.frame(xml_file, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

  x<-xml_file[,c(1,3,7,9)]
  colnames(x)<-c("SITE", "AVAIL_PERCENT", "RESPONSE_TIME", "DATE_TIME")
  x<-x[,c("DATE_TIME", "SITE", "RESPONSE_TIME", "AVAIL_PERCENT")]
  if(coerceDate)
    x$DATE_TIME <- as.POSIXct(x$DATE_TIME, format="%Y-%B-%d %H:%M")

  x$AGENT <- agent
  x
}
```

To call the 2 previous functions :

```
creat.dat <- function(agent,slot){
  res <- NULL
  if(slot==1135863) {
    res <- lapply(1:8,function(k){
      url <- create.URL(solt,agent,k)
      x <- parse.URL(url,agent)
      x
    })
  }else if(slot==1145649){
    res <- lapply(1:6,function(l){
      url <- create.URL(slot,agent,l)
      x <- parse.URL(url,agent,coerceDate=TRUE)
      x
    })
  }
  res
}
```

Finally to call all this , you can use `mapply` to replace the 2 `for` loops:

```
mapply(creat.dat,agentlist,slotlist)
```

Comment: given the agenlist and slot list as this: agentlist<-c(45693,42627,42483,42432,40187) slotlist<-c(1135863,1145649,1135859,1135844), when I call mappyly(create.dat, agetlist, slotlist) will build my whole df? I am sorry I am not following your functions.

Comment: when I ran this df<-mapply(create.dat, agentlist, slotlist), I get this      [,1]   [,2]  
[1,] List,5 List,5
[2,] List,5 List,5
[3,] List,5 List,5
[4,] List,5 List,5
[5,] List,5 List,5
[6,] List,5 List,5
[7,] List,5 List,5
[8,] List,5 List,5

Comment: @user1471980 sorry. there was a mistake in the call of create.URL call , should be `create.URL(slot,agent,l)` and not `create.URL(agent,slot,l)`. I haven't test all the functions together but as I said it is easier to debug function by function now. Try to test each function alone before the final call.

Comment: this seem to work buty mapply is converting it to a matrix of lists. How do you convert this to data frame?

Comment: @user1471980 try something like `do.call(mapply(creat.dat,agentlist,slotlist))`